# How to make module private method in Java modules

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

I want to create a Java IPC server module (with Jigsaw) which has two packages:

- com.example.ipc.backend
- com.example.ipc.backend.api

in my `module-info.java` I have the following export:

```
module ipclib {
    exports com.example.ipc.backend.api;
}
```

I can import this module in my JavaFX GUI module without problems, but I'm having a problem creating a class inside the `api` module.

I have one interface in this class which some class in the GUI module should implement to register itself for changes in the IPC module (e.g. when a client connects to the IPC server):

```
public interface IpcCallback {
    void clientConnected(Client client);
}
```

The class which implements this interface should then receive a `Client` with the information about the connected client. This `Client` class also internally holds a reference to the thread which holds the socket to the client.

```
public class Client {
    private IpcConnection connection; //IpcConnection is from com.example.ipc.backend

    public Client(IpcConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }
}
```

My problem is now that I want to create an instance of `Client` in the non-exported `backend` module, whenever a new connection is created. How can I make the constructor to be only accesible within the module, without making it public?

If I make the constructor public, IntelliJ offers to use the constructor to create a new Client object in the GUI module, but does not have access to the IpcConnection class. It offers a quick fix to export the `backend` module, but this is not what I want when exporting the api.

Therefore, I wonder if this is still “allowed”, because the Java compiler compiles this without any warnings and problems, and it is just a problem of IntelliJ. Or shouldn't this be done like this?

But if this is not the allowed way to do so, I wonder why the module system actually allows exporting only some packages, as there will always be a boundary between exported packages and not-exported packages (only except if the not-exported classes are called from within the exported class, but not the other way round).

### Minimal project

#### Module 'backend'

```
// backend/src/main/java/module-info.java
module ipclib {
    exports com.example.ipc.backend.api;
}
```

```
// backend/src/main/java/com/example/ipc/backend/IpcConnection.java
package com.example.ipc.backend;

public class IpcConnection {
}
```

```
// backend/src/main/java/com/example/ipc/backend/api/Client.java
package com.example.ipc.backend.api;

import com.example.ipc.backend.IpcConnection;

public class Client {
    private IpcConnection connection;
    public Client(IpcConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

```
// backend/src/main/java/com/example/ipc/backend/api/IpcCallback.java
package com.example.ipc.backend.api;

public interface IpcCallback {
    void clientConnected(Client client);
}
```

#### Module 'gui'

```
// gui/src/main/java/module-info.java
module gui {
    requires ipclib;
}
```

```
// gui/src/main/java/com/example/ipc/gui/App.java
package com.example.ipc.gui;

import com.example.ipc.backend.api.Client;
import com.example.ipc.backend.api.IpcCallback;

public class App implements IpcCallback {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    @Override
    public void clientConnected(Client client) {
        System.out.println(client.hello());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow. For instance, you keep using the term "exported module" in places where I _think_ you actually mean "exported package". I'm also not entirely sure what modules you have, which packages are in which module, or which packages each class belongs to. Could you please [edit] your question to make it clearer what your exact setup is, as well as what exactly you're trying to accomplish? In other words, a [mre].

Comment: Thanks, I've added a minimal example.

Comment: I was somewhat confused about "I have one interface in this class" I thought you had a nested interface.

Comment: You can make `Client` an interface, then keep the implementation in a non-exported package.

Comment: Ah, of course. So obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is not possible in java. You can not declare an interface that is "visible in namespace A and all its sub-namespaces").

In contrast to .net, Java does not really know about the "internal" principle.
If you just omit the word `public` on an interface or class definition, this element is only visible inside it's current package.

But this is not recursive, as it is in .net (where you create an `internal` object which is visible only inside the current project, no matter which subfolder or namespace).

In Java, the object is only visible inside its current package (i.e. the very same namespace). Sub-namespaces are not included. Neither are parent namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you have subpackages `A` and `B`, and only `A` is made public. `A` has a class `C` that has a constructor that should be called from `B` but not be made public.

I think your best option is to make class `C` (`Client`) implement and interface that is public. So the interface class can be in the public package and the actual implementation can be in the non-public package.